# Question on self-normalising $p$-subgroups of $p$-groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

Given a finite $p$-group $P$, we call a proper subgroup $Q<P$ **centric** if $C_P(Q)=Z(Q)$.

The question is: can a centric subgroup $Q$ be self-normalising, which means that $N_P(Q)=Q$?

I do not see any reason why not, and yet I am unable to find examples of self-normalising centric subgroups. So I am thinking that the answer is "no, centric implies that it is not self-normalising", but I also cannot prove that.

Comment: No proper subgroup of a finite $p$-group is self-normalizing.

Comment: @DerekHolt ah, this I didn't know, I guess it explains it! Can you point me to a source?

Comment: For one, it is handled [in this very site](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/168963/742).