# Normalizer of subgroup of a finite $p$-group.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, p-groups

I have been struggling with the following exercise for a while now:

Let $p$ be a prime number and $G$ be a finite $p$-group. Show for any real subgroup $H$ of $G$ that $H$ is a real subgroup of the normalizer $N_G(H)$.

In the case $Z(G)\nsubseteq H$ the solution is simple. I have been especially struggling with the case that $Z(G) \subseteq H$.

Anybody have any hints on what theorems to use?

Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Don't you have $H \subset N_G(H)$?

Comment: Yes, that's trivial. But I need to show that $H$ is a real subset of $N_G(H)$. So I should find one element $g \in G\setminus H$ such that $gHg^{-1}=H$.

Comment: Ok by real you mean strict or proper

Comment: If would make a disjunction $H$ is a $p$-group and $H$ is not and use that all $p$ syllow are conjugated?

Comment: What is a "real subgroup"?

Comment: That was asked here before. See here: (though I don't know why in the answer the action was defined on right cosets. IMO it is more natural to act from the left on left cosets) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/168963/proper-subgroups-of-finite-p-groups-are-properly-contained-in-the-normalizer